# OpenCV and Matplotlib show an image in differnt ways

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, opencv3.0

I am trying to plot an image after some processing. I get three different images using the three options below. The image obtained is after applying the Sobel filter twice on a road lane image.

[sample_image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfm8Q.jpg)
The three methods to plot are shown in the below Python code.

```
    img = cv2.imread('sample_image.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)

    sobely = cv2.Sobel(gaussian,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)  # y
    sobelyy = cv2.Sobel(sobely,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)  # y

    # method 1
    cv2.imshow('sobelyy', sobelyy) 

    # method 2
    cv2.imwrite('filtered_img1.JPG', sobelyy)
    s_img = cv2.imread('filtered_img1.JPG')
    cv2.imshow('s_img', s_img)

    # method 3
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(sobelyy, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Filtered sobelyy image, B(x,y)'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
```

The images I get are:

[method 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQMCg.jpg)

[method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPKLl.jpg)

[method 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p6Mj.jpg)

The image I want to get is the one obtained in method 3.

Why are the images shown in different ways?
How can I get to save the output image like the result of method 3?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. the whole code and image necessary to reproduce the stated behaviour. Are you dealing with `float` type images?

Comment: I have summarised the code to make it easier to reproduce. And I'm dealing with uint8 type images. Thank you!

Comment: Your `sobely` and `sobelyy` are `float`, since you set this explicitly here: `cv2.Sobel(gaussian,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)` with any negative and positive values in the corresponding range. OpenCV's `imshow` and `imwrite` methods expect certain types and ranges, e.g. `uint8` and values in the range `[0 ... 255]`. Matplotlib's `imshow` is able to scale any range appropriately. That's a common source of error when working with OpenCV and Matplotlib. Scale `sobelyy` and set its type appropriately, and you'll get the desired result also using OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the images shown in different ways?

OpenCV and Matplotlib use different color spaces to display images - that's why they look differently even when they are actually the same.

As for your first 2 methods those should actually look the same and they do when I try out your code.

> How can I get to save the output image like the result of method 3?

Matplotlib has a build in function to write plotted images to disc, just use:

```
plt.savefig('your_filename.png')
```